# Unique popup window using window.open in an iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have an iFrame with a window open(`url`,`uniqueID`,`windowparams`).
The iFrame is located on a single page app and hosted in another server.
Everytime I refresh or change the page then return to the IFrame page, then try to initiate the same `window.open`. Instead of refreshing the already opened window, it creates an instance of the same window. Upon checking the `window.name` of each popup, it returns the same `uniqueID` as its `window name`. If the url is set blank it behaves as expected. But when a url is set, it creates a new instance of the window.

- Do iFrame `window.open` behave like that when destroyed?
- I tried running the iFrame source locally and the window open behaves properly even after refreshing.
- I tried in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, and it returned the same behaviour.

#### UPDATE:

Mike successfully fixed the behavior for Webkit browsers by added sandbox properties for the iFrame source. Now the `window.open` method works as intended and not creating new instances of the same window of the same `window.name`.

However, Mike still has no luck with Firefox. If someone could give a work around for this, it would be much appreciated.

The Webkit browser behaviour for an iFrame with sanboxed properties in the video below.

> See that the parent, even when refreshed still can detect that there is an already opened popup of the same name.
>   https://youtu.be/z5_xXRjY8Ow

The Firefox behaviour for an iFrame with sanboxed properties in the video below.

> When the parent window is refreshed, the browser could not detect the already opened popup and creates another instance of the pop up with the same `window.name`.
>   https://youtu.be/uHaDveW1Sd0

Is there a workaround to make Firefox behave like Webkit browsers?

#### UPDATE:

Mike found out that using a blank url in window.open behave properly in firefox.
But still how to fix this haha.

#### UPDATE:

Here's Johnny! er Mike means another test case.
Try using webkit browsers and firefox.
After opening a popup, refresh the page then open another popup
webkit browsers will only have one instance of thy window, however firefox will create a new one.
`console.log(window.name)` on the opened popup window and you shall get 'Mike' as the window name
https://bug1295839.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8782242

Comment: Mike should provide a [mcve]

Comment: I get the same behavior in Firefox as I do with Chrome with a small exception in position:  Chrome window pops up in the upper left corner of screen whilst with Firefox, the window pops up above the iframe. Tested on Win10 PC.

Comment: Mike added a video reference so you could see the desired reference.
Creating an iframe using fiddle wasnt behaving as expected

Comment: I am Mike's burning desire to change third-person references to singular... wait.

Comment: Haha sorry boss, Mike thinks Mike has a serious case of Illeism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like t'is a chrome bug

> > https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1295839
> >     https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=640620

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems that I see in your code:

1. You are calling a function that are nested inside another function to close the window, that never gets triggered because parent function is not callable at this time.

   ```
   function openWin(){
        /* code */
   }
   function closeWin(){
        /* code */
   }
   ```
2. To insure browser compatibility to close the Window, I strongly suggest to set and call an injectable function inside generated popup from parent window

Example to inject a function:

```
myWindow.document.write(
        "<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>"
        +"<script>"
        +"function closeWindow()\{" // sample injected function
        +"window.close();"
        +"\}<\/script>"
    );
```

Full Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>

var myWindow;
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write(
        "<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>"
        +"<script>"
        +"function closeWindow()\{" // sample injected function
        +"window.close();"
        +"\}<\/script>"
    );    
}
function closeWin() {
        if(!myWindow.closeWindow) {
            setTimeout(closeWin,1000); // repeat if function not found
        } else { 
            myWindow.closeWindow();
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Michael Rosales, if the answer is correct please accept it.